# How to swap colors of 2 objects

Tags: java, colors

Here's my code in question:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import sun.java2d.loops.DrawRect;

import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Board extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
//instance variables
private int width;
private int height;
private Block topLeft;
private Block topRight;
private Block botLeft;
private Block botRight;

public Board()  //constructor
{
    width = 200;
    height = 200;
    topLeft=new Block(0,0,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.RED);
    topRight=new Block(width/2,0,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.GREEN);
    botLeft=new Block(0,height/2,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.BLUE);
    botRight=new Block(width/2,height/2,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.YELLOW);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setVisible(true);
    //start trapping for mouse clicks
    addMouseListener(this);
}

//initialization constructor
public Board(int w, int h)  //constructor
{
    width = w;
    height = h;
    topLeft=new Block(0,0,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.RED);
    topRight=new Block(width/2,0,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.GREEN);
    botLeft=new Block(0,height/2,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.BLUE);
    botRight=new Block(width/2,height/2,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.YELLOW);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setVisible(true);
    //start trapping for mouse clicks
    addMouseListener(this);
}



public void update(Graphics window)
{
    paint(window);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics window)
{
super.paintComponent(window);
topRight.draw(window);
topLeft.draw(window);
botRight.draw(window);
botLeft.draw(window);


}

public void swapTopRowColors()
{
Color temp = topLeft.getColor(topRight);
topRight.setColor(temp);
repaint();
 }

public void swapBottomRowColors()
{



}

public void swapLeftColumnColors()
{



}

public void swapRightColumnColors()
{



}
```

How would I swap the colors of 2 of these "squares" using the `.getColor()` method? I'm thinking I'm on the right track to achieving it but haven't had to do something like this with colors before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to use `setColor()`, but before that you need to create a temp of one of the colours.

```
public void swapColors(Block g1, Block g2) {
    Color c = g1.getColor();
    g1.setColor(g2.getColor());
    g2.setColor(c);
    repaint();
}
```

Also using this method header, you can swap two colours from the `Block` objects without needing a different method for each combination, just pass through the two you want to swap as arguments.

EDIT:

It seems you need to add a getters and setters to your Block class for `color`, so just add:

```
public Color getColor() {
    return this.color; 
}

public void setColor(Color c) {
    this.color = c;
}
```

Comment: the error I keep getting is claiming that I need to have getColor in my Block class, but that shouldn't be necessary, right?

Comment: so maybe like `private Color temp = 0,0,0;`?

Comment: What does your `Block` class look like?

Comment: Yes, now edited to reflect that. Also, you might want to edit your original post with the `Block` class in there too, so as to give all the information that's relevant to the problem.

Comment: Thanks, given that, I should be able to get the others figured out and the remaining functions

Answer (score 1):

```
public void swapTopRowColors()
{
    Color temp = topLeft.getColor(topRight);
    topLeft.setColor(topRight.getColor()); //<-- line you're missing
    topRight.setColor(temp);
    repaint();
}
```

=== Following comment ===

you'll need to add getter and setter in your `Block` class:

```
public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this `Description Resource Path Location Type
The method getColor() is undefined for the type Block Board.java /Lab10_boolean/10f line 75 Java Problem` when I use your solution (it makes the most sense to me)

Comment: your `Block` class does not seem to have the method `getColor()`

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 almost indentical constructors Board() and Board(h,w), su in default constructor call:

```
public Board()  //constructor
{
    Board(200,200);
}
```

If you use this method, in future you will need to edit only one constructor, not both.